# python sympy solve doesn't solve answer if symbol from local_dic is solved for

Tags: python, sympy

I am using symy to create an equation, sub in values and calculate the answer

```
import math #math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *

V = symbols("V")
I = symbols("I")
Q = symbols("Q")
values = [V,I,Q]

eq = "Q*I-V"
unit_dic ={"I": values[1],"Q":values[2]}#replaces representing values with symbols

eq = parse_expr(eq, local_dict=unit_dic)#converts to sympy equation and pass the replaced units

#subs values
eq = eq.subs("I",20)
eq = eq.subs("V",10)

#solves and prints anwer
answer = solve(eq,Q)
print(answer)
```

If i solve for t then there is no issue the values are replaced andthe answer is output as expected but if i solve for either Q or I it does not work and outputs `[]` where there should be a value eg. [20.0]

I am aware of how sympy uses Q and I to represent other values such as imagonary numbers which is why i am using local_dic to pass it a symbol instead but it is now doing this behavior.

I pass the local dic in the way I do because of how my full program works. i did test passing them in as follows; `local_dict={"I": I,"Q":Q}` but I had the same issue so that is not the problem.

If anyone knows what is happening and why it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as given produces the expected answer, `[V/20]`. In addition, there is no `t` to replace so solving for it should produce `[]`.

Comment: `t`  was a typo. it has been resolved.

Comment: Now it prints `[1/2]` -- there is no problem evident (and you still refer to `t` in the question: "If i solve for t").